# Time complexity of AC-3 algorithm

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, constraint-satisfaction

This is the **AC-3** algorithm's (pseudo) code:

```c
function AC-3(csp) returns false if an inconsistency is found and true otherwise
    queue ← a queue of arcs, initially all the arcs in csp
    while queue is not empty do
        (Xi ,Xj ) ← Pop(queue)
        if Revise(csp,Xi ,Xj ) then
            if size of Di = 0 then return false
            for each Xk in Xi .Neighbors− {Xj } do
                add (Xk,Xi) to queue
    return true

function Revise(csp,Xi ,Xj ) returns true iff we revise the domain of Xi
    revised ← f alse
    for each x in Di do
        if no value y in Dj allows (x, y) to satisfy the constraint between Xi and Xj then
            delete x from Di
            revised ← true
    return revised
```

I'm studying on the book [*Artificial Intelligence - A Modern Approach (4th edition)*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134610997) and this is what it says regarding this algorithm's time complexity:

> Assume a CSP with *n* variables, each with domain size at most *d*, and with binary constraints (arcs). Each arc (Xi, Xj)
> can be inserted in the queue only *d* times because X_i has at most *d* values to delete. Checking
> consistency of an arc can be done in O(d^2) time, so we get O(cd^3) total worst-case time.

- I understand that each arc `(Xi, Xj)` can be inserted in the queue only *d* times (because `Xi` has at most *d* values to delete, and they can be deleted one by one in the worst case).
- I don't understand how checking consistency of a single arc can be done in `O(d^2)`. What I thought it could have been was `O(cd)` instead, since in the worst case it can delete one by one all the values from all the variables' domains.
- I don't understand the total worst-case time it gives, which is `O(cd^3)`. In this case, it would have seemed to me that it could instead have been `O(cd^2)`.

How would you go about calculating the time complexity of this algorithm? Where was I wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how checking consistency of a single arc can be done in O(d^2).

If we look at the REVISE function in the AC-3 algorithm, it says:

```
for each value x in Di:
   if no value y in Dj allows ...
```

We execute the `for` loop in the 1st line above d times and the 2nd line also d times in worst case if we had to search every value in Dj to find a satisfying assignment (x, y) for the constraint (or to determine no satisfying assignment possible).

So that makes O(d^2) to check each arc using AC-3.